# Add a grub menu entry that boots into my current install but with a different runlevel

Tags: grub2, menu, init, runlevel, 14.10

I am running the latest Kubuntu (14.10) and would like to add a grub2 menu entry that allows me to boot straight into a different runlevel? I would like to modify `/etc/rc3.d` or `/etc/rc4.d` to boot straight into the command line and not load X. I believe the custom menu entry should be placed in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`? I assume I can copy my/the default menu entry in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`? but then how do i make this entry boot at a different runlevel?

Can I add the command `telinit 3` to the end of the custom menu entry?

any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem with adding an entry using `40_custom` is that the entry is static - the contents are copied as-is to `grub.cfg`, so a new kernel requires re-editing that file. With very slight tinkering of the `10-linux`, you can get `update-grub` to generate an additional entry for each of the installed kernels. Edit `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`, and after the lines where it says:

```
linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" advanced \
            "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT}"
if [ "x${GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY}" != "xtrue" ]; then
  linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" recovery \
              "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX}"
fi
```

Add another call to `linux_entry`:

```
linux_entry "${OS}, runlevel 3" "${version}" advanced \
          "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT} 3"
```

(Selecting a runlevel is as simple as tacking on the number at the end of the options, IIRC.)

---

Effect:

Menu entry in the "Advanced options" sub menu:
[image: entry]
The contents of that entry:
[image: contents]

Of course, normally runlevels 2-5 are equivalent, so booting from it made no difference to me, except:

```
$ runlevel
N 3
```

Comment: I have just tried this and it works very well :) **Thank You @muru** Now I am going to do a backup then try modifying '/etc/rc3.d' and remove 'lightdm'

Comment: @sinttx Since upstart handles these things now, you should probably be looking at `/etc/init/lightdm.conf`.

Comment: I might have been working from outdated information :( I will do some research into '/etc/init/lightdm.conf' as described. Thanks again @muru

Comment: I have managed to achieve this by updating the 10-linux file.

Has anyone worked out how /etc/init/lightdm.conf is meant to be used to achieve the same thing (i.e. alternative to start in console only without X)?

Comment: @hyg53 typiclly you just disable lightdm if you don't want it to start (e.g., `systemctl disable lightdm.service`, since these days its systemd and not Upstart)

Comment: I see. Not directly what is being asked then as it would require to start x manually each time rather than just have this as an option in grub (for use when the videao drivers are playing up for instannce...).

Comment: @hyg53 if that's the case, and you're using recent versions of Debian and Ubuntu, there won't be a `/etc/init/lightdm.conf`, and you'd just need to boot to runlevel 3 ([technically `multiuser.target`](https://askubuntu.com/a/788465/158442))

Comment: I've used this successfully on Mint 19 through 21.1 - sometimes when I update my nvidia drivers, they break things (as nvidia likes to do for some reason), and this allows me to fix it - Thanks @muru!