# Ubuntu Server allow only specific user to use gui

Tags: server, mate

I want to install a graphical Interface on my ubuntu-server machine. But I dont want it to start up at system start to every user. Is it possible to start the ubuntu mate core session per user?

Comment: Already implemented: The graphical desktop stack does NOT start at system boot. Only Plymouth starts at boot (it's the login screen, and it's completely independent of the graphical desktop). While awaiting login, the entire graphical desktop stack is not running nor even loaded. The graphical desktop environments only begins loading and running after a successful login.

Comment: How can I disable it for every user but one?

Comment: Here is a tutorial that might help you: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/restrict-linux-users-from-gdm-kdm-login-but-allow-ssh/

Comment: You can make the computer start in [text mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900985/how-can-i-simply-change-into-a-text-mode-runlevel-under-systemd) and let the user select graphics mode from the command line console with `startx`. It should work with Ubuntu MATE.You can also create a [simple graphical system with a window manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398) (and add only the tools you really need). Please notice that it can also work via `ssh -X` from another computer.