# How to turn off Ubuntu 17.10's GUI (GDM)?

Tags: 17.10

Unlike 17.04, `sudo service stop gdm` or `sudo service stop lightdm` will return `stop: unrecognized service`, so my question being how to stop the GUI process in this bleeding edge version?

Comment: There is an error in the command you are using: You must use `sudo service gdm stop` (`stop gdm` is a mistake)

Answer (score 9):

Instead of killing the `gdm`, you can *change the systemd target*.

---

**Changing the systemd target**

As mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/788465/292470), starting from 16.04, Ubuntu uses `systemd` and the boot process relies on a set of `targets`. Each `target` defines the system software that Ubuntu must run.

This is a list of `targets` for Ubuntu:

```
   ┌───────────────────┐
   │ Target            │
   ├───────────────────┤
   │ poweroff.target   │ turn off the computer
   ├───────────────────┤
   │ rescue.target     │ minimal for admin/rescue tasks
   ├───────────────────┤
   │ multi-user.target │ multi-user, no GUI
   ├───────────────────┤
   │ graphical.target  │ multi-user, GUI
   ├───────────────────┤
   │ reboot.target     │ reboot the computer
   └───────────────────┘
```

To stop the GUI, you can change the `target`. The system checks all the running system software and kills those not included in the specified target. In consequence, if you change to the `multi-user.target` target, the GUI will be killed.

To change the "target" and kill the GUI:

```
sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

To make this the default "target" (and start booting your computer without GUI), you can use:

```
sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 3):

To stop:

```
sudo telinit 3
```

To start:

```
sudo telinit 5
```

Answer (score 2):

To stop it:

```
sudo systemctl gdm stop
```

To disable it completely:

```
sudo systemctl gdm disable
```

To start it:

```
sudo systemctl gdm start
```

and to re-enable it:

```
sudo systemctl gdm enable
```

To see the actually running services

```
systemctl --state running
```

Comment: I had problems after stoping the graphical user interface in this way. In my computer I was not able to get a console to log in. Instead of, I am [changing the `systemd target`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788323/change-runlevel-on-16-04). That command stops all the GUI without restarting the computer.